# ElasticSearch on Raspberry Pi exited

Tags: linux, elasticsearch, raspberry-pi, debian, raspbian

I'm trying to run ElasticSearch on Raspbian on my Raspberry Pi 3. After simply running `sudo apt install elasticsearch` it installed A LOT of things, and then I tried `sudo service elasticsearch status`, which gives the following result:

```
$ sudo service elasticsearch status
● elasticsearch.service - LSB: Starts elasticsearch
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/elasticsearch)
   Active: active (exited) since Thu 2017-02-16 23:28:52 UTC; 1s ago
  Process: 6022 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/elasticsearch stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 6063 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/elasticsearch start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
```

I don't really get what this `active (exited)` means. I tried getting the ElasticSearch version, but that also failed:

```
$ curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200'
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 9200: Connection refused
```

Does anybody know what is wrong and how I can proceed from here?

Comment: What logs are saying?

Comment: @VolodymyrBilyachat - There are no log files in `/var/log/elasticsearch`, the folder is empty. Any other ideas?

Comment: Do you have Java instaled? You could also try to install the elasticsearch manually/ through a binary/deb. Check this link: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-elasticsearch-on-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: Right after installing, you are directly checking the status, it is checking if it is able to start the server. Try to start the server using “sudo service elasticsearch start” and then do “curl”.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the end I managed to get it running. I had to install Java 8

```
sudo apt-get purge openjdk-7-jdk
sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk
```

and set the memory maximum lower by opening `/etc/elasticsearch/jvm.options` and replacing

```
-Xms2G
-Xmx2G
```

with

```
-Xms256M
-Xmx256M
```

Restarting ES (`sudo service elasticsearch start`) solved it for me.

Comment: Did it really work with you? I still get cannot allocate enough memory error

Comment: @MohammedNoureldin - Yes it did really work with me after doing this (although by now I don't use it anymore). Unfortunately I don't have any other tips than this. I hope you get it working as well!

Comment: Those changes in `jvm.options` works perfect for me! thank you very much! I was trying to change them from `sysctl`, not directly from `jvm.options` like you did, therefore they didn't work.

Comment: @MohammedNoureldin There is no file named `jvm.options`. I am using latest raspbian stretch.

Comment: @SAndrew, I cannot exactly remember, but it guess there should be such file in elasticsearch directory-

Answer (score 0):

At time of posting, installing through `apt-get install elasticsearch` on latest Raspbian release installs Elasticsearch 1.7 (which does not use `/etc/elasticsearch/jvm.options`)

Go to https://www.elastic.co/downloads/elasticsearch and get the link for the .deb package. Then install it with the following:

```
cd /home/pi
wget https://artifacts.elastic.co/downloads/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-6.6.1.deb
dpkg -i elasticsearch-6.6.1.deb
```

Once you've done that you'll be able to edit `/etc/elasticsearch/jvm.options` and then start elasticsearch.

Comment: How did you get this to work because the only deb package is amd64.deb and pi's are armhf.

Comment: I think that might be for ES 7.x, they have all their older releases with don't seem to specify an infrastructure (for example latest 6.x would be https://www.elastic.co/downloads/past-releases/elasticsearch-6-8-0)

Comment: For the full list see https://www.elastic.co/downloads/past-releases#elasticsearch